# Prettier extension not working in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I am trying to use Prettier in vs code but it's not formating my code from few days. Few days ago it was working great but not now. It's giving me error in settings.json.
My settings.json is like

```
    {
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact"
    },
    "editor.fontSize": 20,
    {
        "window.zoomLevel": 2,
        "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
        "prettier.singleQuote": true
    }
}
```

It's giving me error on line no 7

Comment: remove the `{` from line 7 and the matching `}` on line 13

Comment: Yes, try solution provided by @rioV8
It might solve your error.

Comment: Yes this resolve my issue

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same problem once.

1. Select `VS Code` -> `View` -> `Command Palette`, and type: `Format Document With`
2. Then `Configure Default Formatter..` and then choose `Prettier - Code formatter`.

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed it on my Linux machine.

1. Go to VS Code Settings -> type formatter -> choose Prettier - Code formatter as Default Formatter
2. Also select Format On Save

This fixed it for me.